# Lazy<T> reinitialization method?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

We have a homebrew type that we have been using since .NET 3.5 where I work that does the same thing as Lazy< T > class yet allows you to have the instance re-evaluate the Lazy Func. We would like to replace our class with the new .NET one but this Clear() or IsDirty mechanism doesn't exist.

Is there a way to reinitialize the Lazy< T > Func method without reinstantiating the class? If not, is there a way to implement it as an extension method or is just just a bad pattern to follow in the first place?

Comment: I guess because it is to be seen as a value and another value is not the same value.

Comment: It looks like you want to re-creating the instances lazily? If so then that's not the intent of this (or any lazy initialization class for that matter) class. The instance gets created once, but only just before it is used (and only if it is used).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset System.Lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961252/reset-system-lazy)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it is impossible to make it thread-safe.  Classes that *guarantee* that the programmer will shoot his leg off without any way to fix the problem don't belong in a framework.  You are free to shoot your own leg off.

Answer (score 8):

What you want to do isn't Lazy initialization, it's something else. That's why it isn't on the `Lazy<T>` class.

Answer (score 5):

Because that would break the semantics of the type. If the state of the `Lazy<T>` becomes invalid over time you need to consider a different type.

Answer (score 5):

If you really need to reset your Lazy<> object you need to have the mechanism to make new instance of Lazy<> type. You could build a wrapper that exposes the same properties as Lazy<> type plus Reset-method which simply recreates it. In simple terms it would be something like:

```
public class ResettableLazy<T>
{
    public T Value => this.Container.Value;
    public bool IsValueCreated => this.Container.IsValueCreated;
    public void Reset() { this.Container = new Lazy<T>(); }
    private Lazy<T> Container = new Lazy<T>();
}
```

The real question is should you do something like that, but if you really need to that might be enough for your needs.